# Symmetric-config-multi-master.sql file not found

Tags: symmetricds

I have installed Symmetric-ds-pro 3.12.2 on my 3 servers and configured multi-master replication among them. The node.properties file on my 1st server, created an entry `auto.config.registration.svr.sql.script=/symmetric-config-multi-master.sql`.

But nowhere I am able to find `symmetric-config-multi-master.sql` on my server. Where can i find it?

Comment: What’s the operating system SymmetricDS is running on?

Comment: windows 10 pro, 64 bit

Comment: You will need to create, edit such a file and save it in a folder. Then here should come the fully qualified path to the file that includes the letter of the disk, all folders from the root to the folder which hold the file and the file name